# Django open link which does pre-set things (click "men" on e-ccomerce site and have it automatically filter on men's clothing

Tags: python, django, hyperlink, django-views

Sorry about the rubbish title, I wasn't sure what to put, if anyone has any improvements, please comment and I will update accordingly.

### Problem

I currently am working on an e-commerce website, and have finished setting up the shop section (where you can view products and filter based on your needs), now on the navbar and other locations, I have names such as "Men" or "Women",

**What I need is that these links go to the shop page and automatically filter based on the link**

So if I click "men", it should go to the shop page, and return back the items already filtered showing men's products (preferably all the options inside of the men category should already be ticked, but this is not necessary). Then you can carry on adjusting your filter as required as if you clicked on the shop page directly.

### Soulutions Tried

First of all, I tried to set up a system where you can use a dynamic URL to see the link coming from, for example, "shop/women", but this would need be exactly the same as "shop/" just with the filtering, I tried to add this into my urls.py file like this

```
    path('shop/<str:category>/', Shop.as_view(), name="shop"),
```

I'm definitely doing something wrong since even when I try to manually try this in, it doesn't work, and raises a NoReverseMatch found an error. I tried to have a look on the web but couldn't find a solution to this.

I'd also appreciate some help with the filtering system as well, but that doesn't have to be in the answer, the main thing that I need is some sort of way to be able to grab the information and filter on it. I think this should be relatively easy for anybody with a decent amount of experience with Django,

**thank you very much in advance**

### Code

I put all the relevant code I see necessary, but if anyone needs any more then please just ask

**models.py product class**

```
# Product details
class Product(models.Model):
    # name
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    # price
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    # date added, i can use this to figure out if the item is new
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    # Whether the item is in stock
    in_stock = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    # If the product is on sale
    sale = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    # the price for sale, this can be blank since there won't always be a sale on
    sale_price = models.DecimalField(null=True, blank=True, max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)

    # times sold, use this for bestsellers, not sure how to do this though
    times_sold = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

    # gender type, uses the GENDER_CHOICES, use this in search and homepage
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=256, choices=GENDER_CHOICES, default='women')
    # Items to show on homepage,  so bestseller will show up on bestseller
    home_page_show = models.CharField(max_length=256, choices=DOING_WELL_CHOICES, default='no')
    # Choices for the category to place the product into, we zip it to make it Django compliant
    # ('actual value','human readable value')
    category = models.CharField(max_length=256, choices=zip(CATEGORY_CHOICES, CATEGORY_CHOICES), default='women-coat')

    # Here are all the images
    thumbnail = models.ImageField()
    image_1 = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    image_2 = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    image_3 = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    image_4 = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)

    # PRODUCT DETAIL FIELDS
    LOREM_IPSUM = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.'

    brand = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True, default=LOREM_IPSUM)
    head_description = models.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=True, default=LOREM_IPSUM)
    description_1 = models.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=True, default=LOREM_IPSUM)
    description_2 = models.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=True, default=LOREM_IPSUM)
    specification_1 = models.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=True, default=LOREM_IPSUM)
    specification_2 = models.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=True, default=LOREM_IPSUM)

    # SIZES AVAILABLE
    xxs = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    xs = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    xss = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    s = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    m = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    ml = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    l = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    xl = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    # COLOURS AVAILABLE
    colour = models.CharField(default='red', choices=COLOUR_CHOICES, max_length=256)

    # String Representation
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    # This function just makes sure we don't get an error if we try to load an image
    # that doesn't exist, it tries to get the url, and if that fails, returns an empty string
    def thumbnailurl(self):
        try:
            url = self.thumbnail.url
        except:
            url = ''
        return url

    # We're going to do the same thing here, except iterate through all the images and try each one individually
    # this way, we can get as many working images as possible
    def imagesurl(self):
        # Set an empty string as images to store all the urls
        images = []
        # Iterate through each image
        for image in [self.image_1, self.image_2, self.image_3, self.image_4]:
            # Try except to catch any errors
            try:
                # Try to add the image url to the list
                images.append(image.url)
            # image doesn't exist
            except:
                # Add a blank
                images.append('')
        # Return the final product
        return images
```

**views.py for shop**

```
class Shop(ListView):
    # Set the model as Product, the rest is handled by Django
    model = Product
    # Name of HTML File to show
    template_name = 'store/shop.html'
    # What to refer to in the HTML file (injection)
    context_object_name = 'products'

    # If the request.method is POST (a filter request)
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Function from utils.py
        min_price, max_price, products = filter_shop(request)
        print(min_price, max_price)

        # Function from utils.py
        data = cartData(self.request)
        # Assigning keys to keys in context which can then be referenced in the html
        # Pass is in the completed query as a option, plus cartitems for the cart
        context_dict = {'products': products, 'cartitems': data['cartItems'], 'min_price': min_price,
                        'max_price': max_price, 'categories':category_choices()}
        return render(request, 'store/shop.html', context_dict)

    def get_context_data(self, *args, object_list=None, **kwargs):
        # Call the base implementation first to get a context
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # Function from utils.py
        data = cartData(self.request)
        # Assigning keys to keys in context which can then be referenced in the html
        context['cartitems'] = data['cartItems']
        # Wishlist
        context['wishlistitems'] = data['wishlistitems']

        # Min and max for slider
        context['min_price'], context['max_price'] = 33, 99

        context['categories'] = category_choices()
        return context
```

**urls.py for store app**

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import *

app_name = 'store'

urlpatterns = [
    # Index
    path('', Index.as_view(), name="index"),
    # Shop, like searching
    path('shop/', Shop.as_view(), name="shop"),
    # Detail view of product
    path('detail/<int:pk>', ProductDetail.as_view(), name="detail"),

    # Cart and wishlist view, they are basically both the same
    path('cart/', Cart.as_view(), name="cart"),
    path('wishlist/',WishListView.as_view(),name="wishlist"),
    # checkout view
    path('checkout/', Checkout.as_view(), name="checkout"),
    # contact page, STILL NEED TO ADD IN BLOG
    path('contact/',Contact.as_view(),name="contact"),
    # Function which runs to update the cart, look at views.py
    path('update_item/', updateItem, name="update_item"),
    # Function which runs to update the wishlist, very similar to above, look at views.py
    path('update_wishlist/',updateWishList,name="update_wishlist"),
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there are a a few solutions to the problem you are having.

Lets start with the urls.  I think the problem you might be having is if you had these two lines in there together:

```
path('shop/', Shop.as_view(), name="shop"),
path('shop/<str:category>/', Shop.as_view(), name="shop"),
```

These names need to be unique, so you should call the second one "shop_category" or something like that.  Another potential issue: don't forget to add a "/" at the end of your urls.  So you had this:

```
path('shop/<str:category>', Shop.as_view(), name="shop"),
```

But that needs to be this:

```
path('shop/<str:category>/', Shop.as_view(), name="shop"),
```

If you are going to start having a more complex structure for shop that included different views, than I would suggest switching urls to an app structure.  To do this, create a folder called urls and add what you have as your **init**.py, but instead of adding shop as a view, include another list of urls as a namespace.

```
urls/__init__.py

from django.urls import path, include


app_name = 'store'
urlpatterns = [
    path('shop/', include('urls.shop', namespace='shop')),
    (everything else as you have it)
]
```

Then you can add another file called shop.py and put things specific to that namespace.

```
urls/shop.py

from django.urls import path
from .views import *

app_name = 'store'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', Shop.as_view(), name="index"),
    path('mens/', Shop.as_view(), name="shop"),
]
```

This might be overkill for you speecific situation.  I would mostly recommend this approach if you need to use actually different views.  With this approach you can link to these using revers("shop:mens") or whatever you name patterns.

The last bit of advice (and maybe this should have been the first bit) I would give is to look into django-tables2 and django-filters if you have not.  This greatly simplifies both generating tables from querysets and filtering that data using query strings.  So instead of having to pass just the category to your view, you can pass a long query string like "http://www.example.com/shop/?category=mens&size=small&foo=bar".  This will tell your view how to filter these three metrics all at once.  Even if you don't implement django-filters, I would recommend doing your filtering this way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately, the first option has already been tested by me, I tried to do that but get the "Reverse for 'shop' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['shop/(?P<category>[^/]+)/$']" error, if you could help me with that, that would be great, and I'd accept your answer, as for the second option, I'd much rather not have to do that since it would be way too overkill for something relatively simple, with the whole Django filtering, I personally really like having no extra information in the URL bar, even at the cost of the development, user experience first.

Comment: I've just found out that if only the shop URL doesn't work if I make another URL called shop_category then it works fine, but if I do the exact same thing but just shop, even just on the original, it raises the error. Thank you very much in advance.